# Stream Error in Soap Connection

Tags: java, android, soap, http-post, httpurlconnection

I develop android application in java. And, this application connects .net soap application. It is ok, it works (i use http post method). 
My actual problem is web service returns big and huge (especially contains html --cdata source code) data.
So, when i request (such as, getReports methods) to web service, it returns about 3 - 5 mb stream data, causes outofmemory. Because of this, i couldn't parse it. I know my connection method cannot be true.
How can i implement truely if i make a mistake?

Thanks in advance.

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/lorem";
String SURL = "http://www.test.com/lorem/test.asmx";
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
xml += "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:web=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
        + "<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body>"
        + "<web:getReport><web:strLang>strLang</web:strLang></web:getReport>"
        + "</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bout.write(xml.getBytes());
byte[] b = bout.toByteArray();
httpconn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", Namespace+ "/" + "getReport");
httpconn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");
httpconn.setRequestProperty("Host","www.test.com");
httpconn.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpconn.setDoInput(true);
httpconn.setDoOutput(true);
httpconn.connect();
OutputStream out = httpconn.getOutputStream();
out.write(b);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

String inputLine = "";
StringBuffer parsingData = new StringBuffer();
while (null != (inputLine = in.readLine())) {
    // OutOfMemory Error
    parsingData.append(inputLine);
}

/*
* parsingMethods (parsingData); 
*/
```

Comment: Have you tryed KSOAP ? http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse

Comment: Yes, i tried to alots methods. Such as, first of all saved sdcard as file, then read - parse it. But, everydevice has not sdcard. It is not. As an other method, i create a jsp web server which request to .net server, and returns data as parsing. Finally, i get it easily, It is not. Lastly, i tried to do ksoap. It doesnt support my http headers.. puff,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ksoap does support headers here is how

```
Element AuthHeader = new Element();
AuthHeader.setName("Auth");
AuthHeader.setNamespace(namespace);

Element element = new Element();
element.setName("Username");
element.setNamespace(namespace);
element.addChild(Element.TEXT, username);
AuthHeader.addChild(Element.ELEMENT, element);

element = new Element();
element.setName("Password");
element.setNamespace(namespace);
element.addChild(Element.TEXT, password);
AuthHeader.addChild(Element.ELEMENT, element);

headers[0] = AuthHeader;

envelope.headerOut = headers;
```

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, but my problem is large data. Web service returns 3 - 5mb stream data. application anyway causes outofmemory during gets all stream data.